# Binary to decimal converter

Tags: c++, beginner, number-systems

I started a few weeks ago to learn C++ online. I just made a little binary → decimal program. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i,j=1;
    long long decimal=0, powerOfTwo=1;
    cin>>i;
    char binary[i];
    i*=2;
    while (i)
    {
        if (i > j)
        {
           cin>>binary[j];
           ++j;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<binary[i];
            if (i%4 == 1) //adds a space after 4 numbers (eg. 1011 0111 instead of 10110111)
                cout<<" ";
            if (binary[i] == '1')
                decimal += powerOfTwo;
            powerOfTwo *= 2;
        }
        --i;
    }
    cout<<"in ten base is equal to "<<decimal;
    return 0;
}
```

So I want to know, am I heading in the right direction? Please let me know what I am not doing good or any kind of suggestion.

Comment: The only "C++" here is `cin, cout, using namespace std;`.

Comment: Can you be more specific ? Should i start with C language ?

Comment: @Undyne It depends. Note that we can always write code. However, if you want to become more productive, it makes sense to use [standard library](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/). There is a saying: good programmers program, best programmers *reuse*.

Comment: @Undyne Do you use a book, or online examples to learn C++?

Comment: @Zeta I'm learning from [here](http://www.learncpp.com)

Comment: There is no conversion to decimal here, apart from the final print. You're just converting binary-coded ASCII to binary.

Comment: @EJP Actually it is not guaranteed the internal representation is binary. However you're right, there is no conversion to decimal in this program, it's `cout<<decimal` which makes the conversion.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## What would Bob do?

You've written an interactive program, but the user does not know what your program does. Therefore, Bob—the generic user—might accidentally write "test" instead of a number, and suddenly your program runs wild.

A first step in the right direction would be to tell the user what your program will do—as long as its interactive. Note that this is not C++ specific.

We can do so by starting with:

```
cout << "This program converts a binary number to a decimal one\n"
        "Please state the length of your number: ";
```

But that's error prone. First of all, Bob might not know how long the binary number is. Try to check whether `1101011010101101` is 14 or 15 characters long. That's a trick question, those are 16 characters.

So instead, just let Bob write anything and then check how long it is and whether it was really a binary number.

## Prefer `std::string` to `char[N]`

Instead of `char binary[i]`, we will use a `std::string binary`. This makes the input a lot easier. However, to handle the input easier, let's write a function. Actually, let's write two:

```
bool is_binary_number(const std::string& binary){
    return std::all_of(binary.begin(), binary.end(), [](char c){
        return c == '0' || c == '1';
    });
}
```

That's using C++11's `all_of` in combination with a lambda. In case you don't know that yet, here's the same variant written in a range-based `for` loop:

```
bool is_binary_number(const std::string& binary){
    for(char c : binary) {
        if(c != '0' && c != '1') {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

But this is C++11 syntax. In case you're not familar with C++11 at all, it's almost the same as

```
bool is_binary_number(const std::string& binary){
    for(size_t i = 0; i < binary.size(); ++i) {
        if(binary[i] != '0' && binary[i] != '1') {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

In case you don't know `std::string &` yet, that's a reference. A reference is an alias to an already existing object. A `const` reference is an alias where we cannot change the value:

```
int        value = 15;
int&       ref   = value;
const int& cref  = value;

ref = 12;

std::cout << value << std::endl; // prints 12, since we changed it via ref
std::cout << cref  << std::endl; // prints 12, since we changed it via ref

// does not compile:
cref = 7;           // error; this reference is read only!
```

The details are a little bit more complicated, but in the end, when we call `is_binary_number(on_a_string)`, we won't make a copy of `on_a_string`.

Either way, now that we have a function to check whether a string is a binary number, we can write our function to ask Bob for input:

```
std::string ask_binary_number() {
    std::cout << "Please enter a binary number: ";

    while(true) {
        std::string input;
        std::cin >> input;

        if(is_binary_number(input)) {
            return input;  
        } else {
            std::cout << "That wasn't a binary number, try again: ";
        }
    }
}
```

We can now use this in `main`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>        // necessary for std::string

int main () {
    std::string binary = ask_binary_number();

    ...
}
```

Note that we don't need to touch `main` at all if we want to change the input method later on. We only need to change `ask_binary_number`. This makes it easy to ask the user for another number, or re-use `ask_binary_number` in another project.

**Exercise:** Usually, you don't want leading zeroes in binary numbers. Which function do you have to change to not allow leading zeroes in the result of `ask_binary_number`? What changes are necessary?

## Keep it simple and stupid

In your `for` loop, you do two things at once: you print the binary number *and* convert the number to a decimal. Unless you know that this is a bottleneck in your program and you need cache locality or something similar to keep your code fast, do one thing and one thing only. This makes it a lot easier to change the code later without breaking something else.

We can split this functionality again into two functions:

```
void print_binary_with_spaces(const std::string & binary, size_t digits = 4){
    // exercise; almost solved by your own code
}

unsigned long binary_to_decimal(const std::string & binary){
    // exercise; almost solved by your own code
}
```

If you implement all functions given above, you end up with the following `main`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// functions here (either completely or only their declaration)

int main() {
    std::cout << "This program converts a binary number to a decimal one." << std::endl;
    std::string binary = ask_binary_number();

    std::cout << "Your binary number ";

    print_binary_with_spaces(binary);

    std::cout << " is " << binary_to_decimal(binary) << "in decimal"
              << std::endl;
}
```

Note that all *complex* interactions are moved into functions. However, as you have seen in `ask_binary_number` and `is_binary_number` those functions aren't complex themselves either. Keeping things simple is a principle (*KISS*) that's often applied, as is splitting the functionality (*separation of concerns*).

### A concrete example of overly complex code

Why am I pointing to simplicity? Because your `while` loop is overly complex:

```
i = i * 2;
j = 1;
while (i)
{
    if (i > j)        
    {
       ...            // lets call this A
       ++j;
    }
    else
    {
        ...          // lets call this B
    }
    --i;
}
```

Essentially, you have the following **loops**:

```
for(j = 0; j < i; ++j)
{
    A; // see above
}

for(--i; i > 0; --i)
{
    B; // see above
}
```

If we used that in your program, it would look like this:

```
for(int j = 0; j < i; ++j){
    cin >> binary[j];
}

while(i-- > 0){
    cout << binary[i];
    if (i%4 == 1) 
        cout << " ";
    if (binary[i] == '1')
        decimal += powerOfTwo;
    powerOfTwo *= 2;
}
```

This is not only easier to understand, it's even shorter. So try to keep your loops simple.

Comment: Instead of `is_binary_number`, you can use `std::all_of`. Always prefer a standard library algorithm if there is one :)

Comment: @Rakete1111 that would use a lambda, and I'm not sure our beginner is ready for that one, yet the `<algorithm>` header at all. Always prefer the code that's easier to understand.

Comment: You have a point. But I'd rather mention it and have OP maybe not understand it, then to not mention it at all. You can't learn anything if you don't know what you don't know :)

Comment: @Rakete1111 I've added it, although there are now three variants of `is_binary_number`. They will all compile to the same loop, I guess, but the first one will compile to at least four questions:  "what's `begin`/`end`? What's that `[](){}` thing? What's `all_of`? What does `template ` on the cppreference mean?". By the way, now we could even go further and define `auto is_binary(auto binary, auto zero ='0', auto one='1') { return ....;}`:D.

Comment: @Zeta Thanks, I understand like 4/5 of the syntax, but you really helped me learn how to organize my code. I'll come back with the full code later. Thanks again !

Comment: @Zeta [Here](https://pastebin.com/pa6Njryv) is the code. I have some questions, if you don't mind: what is the difference between     `string binary` and `string& binary`.  Also`binaryToDecimal()`'s type is `long` but it's return (decimal) is `int`. Should they have same type ?

Comment: @Undyne: You're allowed to ask for follow-up reviews. That being said, now to `string` vs `string&`: the latter is a [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference). A reference is an alias to *an already existing* object/function/value.  Your site handles them [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/611-references/). On the other question: they should have the same type. Your compiler might warn you about that if you enable (more) warnings. In C++14 you can use `auto` to deduce the return type automatically (http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/4-8-the-auto-keyword/).

Comment: @Undyne I've added some examples to the section regarding references.

Comment: @Zeta I tried to the the opposite, [decimal -> binary](https://pastebin.com/X1EJfvUD), but I have some problems with int to string conversion in     decimalToBinary() How should I fix it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67478/discussion-between-zeta-and-undyne).

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead **strtoul** library method in cstdlib
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtoul/

from this you can convert any radix base in string format to unsigned long long number.

**usage-example here :**

```
/* strtoul binary-to-decimal example */

#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<cstdint>
#include<cstdlib>

#define BINARY_BASE 2 /*Defining binary base*/
#define OCTAL_BASE 8  /*Defining octal base*/
#define DECIMAL_BASE 10 /*Defining decimal base*/
#define HEXA_BASE 16    /*Defining hexa-decimal base*/
#define BASE32_BASE 32 /*Defining base32 base*/

bool isValidNumber4Base(const char* numStr,int base)
{

    const char *validBinary = "01";
    const char *validOctal = "01234567";
    const char *validDecimal = "0123456789";
    const char *validHex = "0123456789abcdefxABCDEFX";
    const char *validBase32 = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV";
    const char *validNumber = NULL;

    validNumber = (base == BINARY_BASE) ? validBinary : ((base == OCTAL_BASE) ? validOctal :
                    (base == DECIMAL_BASE) ? validDecimal : (base == HEXA_BASE) ? validHex : (base == BASE32_BASE) ? validBase32 : NULL);

    if(validNumber ==  NULL)
    {
        std::cerr<<"Invalid base encountered"<<std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return (!numStr[strspn(numStr,validNumber)]) ? true : false;
}

uint64_t getDecimal4mBinary(const char *binaryStr)
{
    if (isValidNumber4Base(binaryStr,BINARY_BASE))
    {
        char *endBinaryStr;
        return strtoull(binaryStr,&endBinaryStr,BINARY_BASE);
    }

    else
    {
        std::cerr<<"Invalid binary-number encountered"<<std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

/*Test Method */
int main ()
{
  char *binary_str = "10000001";
  uint64_t dec4mBinary = getDecimal4mBinary(binary_str);    
  std::cout<<"Decimal equivalent\n"<<dec4mBinary<<std::endl;        
  return 0;
}
```

Code Working on C++ 14 compiler :
https://ideone.com/CIOkUM

C version of bin-to-decimal and other binary related stuff could be found here.
https://github.com/haseeb-heaven/BinaryLibrary4C/blob/master/binary4c.h